# HTML Textbox showing default value as 0 for int data field

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a textbox which is holds int data field. When the page loads, 0 appears by default. Following is the code for displaying text box :

```
<%:Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Ssn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "txtBox txtBoxMediumSmall" })%>
```

where model.Ssn is a **int**.
Why isn't is blank? And what should be done to make it blank?
Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: Can you provide the code of you controller's action?

Comment: Int can not be blank or null. Its always default to 0.

Comment: You will have to explicitly apply the logic . that is If model.SSn==0 {TextBox.text=""}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this

```
public class MyModel
{
   //Nullable integer
   public int? Ssn {get; set;}  //this should be null by default

   public int SSN {get; set; } //this should be 0 by default

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As bittech poinetd out int is struct and does not have "empty" value - 0 is default, but perfectly valid value.

You can try to use `int?` (`Nullable<int>`) if you need to destinguish "no value" vs. "default value".

Answer (score 0):

I will do like this -

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Ssn, new { @Value = (@Model.Ssn == 0) ? "" : @Model.Ssn.ToString()})
```